# configuring jest to run tests in a different folder

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have been trying to configure Jest so it could run test cases written in another folder in the same hierarchy. But it throws the below error.

I am trying to run jest from the as_test folder while my test case files and actual code to be tested resides in asCore folder.

I think Jest is unable to find enzyme as it resides in node_modules of as_test,while the test case which uses it resides in asCore folder.

Could someone help me how solve this problem.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'enzyme' from 'Button.test.js'

  1 |
> 2 | import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
    | ^
  3 | import Button from '../JSX/Button';
  4 |
  5 |

  at Resolver.resolveModule (as_test/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (asCore/components/button/__tests__/Button.test.js:2:1)
```

The jest config files and my development reside in the below structure.
[image]

Package.JSON

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "example-enzyme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "16.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",   
    "babel-jest": "*",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "jest": "*",
    "react-test-renderer": "*",
    "enzyme": "*",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "*",
    "enzyme-to-json": "*",
    "jest-html-reporter": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --no-cache"
  }
}
```

Jest.config.js

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const root = resolve(__dirname, '..');
console.log(root);
module.exports = {
    "verbose": true,
    "rootDir": root,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/as_test/config/jestSetup.js",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory":"<rootDir>/as_test/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
        "html", "text"
    ],   
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "<rootDir>/*"],
    "testResultsProcessor": "<rootDir>/as_test/node_modules/jest-html-reporter",
    "snapshotSerializers": ["<rootDir>/as_test/node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "core/extendables/reactHelper$": "<rootDir>/as_test/deps/js/reactHelper.js",
        "core/components/button/JSX-generated/Button$": "<rootDir>/as_test/deps/jsx/Button"
    }
 };
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {

  presets: [['@babel/preset-env'],'@babel/preset-react'],
  
};
```

JestSetup.js

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```